# Problem with åäö and Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to access a script on a domain with åäö in the domain name. But flash consistently generates a security error no matter what I do.

The setup is like this:

**http://www.domän.se/admin.html** (with **http://www.domän.se/admin.swf** embedded)

is trying to access

**http://www.domän.se/script/script.php**

Even with a crossdomain file flash generates a security error, because it considers the script to be on a different domain or something.

edit: Apparently it only appears in Firefox. I've tested the same page with identical flash player versions in several browsers and the bug only seems to appear in Firefox.

Comment: what does the error messages say, they should be rather specific on where from it attempted to load the crossdomain.xml and so on. can you post them maybe?

Comment: Well the error is in swedish so this is a rough translation:


`Error #2044: securityError:. text=Error #2048: Violation of sandbox: http://www.Ã¥vandÃ¤r.se/Admin.swf can not read in data from script/dataManager.php.`

Comment: are you using a relative url or a absolute one?

Comment: I'm using a relative URL: `private var _scriptURL:String = "script/dataManager.php"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative url in your flash file instead of a absolute one.

Comment: Nope, flash still sees it as a security violation. (Error #2044)

The problem is that it mangles the URL, for example å becomes Ã¥.

Comment: if you are using a relative url then you shouldn't be in the need of using the domain name, and if the folders do use åäö then just change their names. (i would explain this to you in Swedish but for the sake of others i'll be writing in English).

Comment: I have to use åäö because it's part of the domain name. Also I don't use the full domain name anywhere in my code but flash still uses it when checking for security violations. For some reason in firefox it thinks the root directory where I have my flash files is a different domain than the subdirectory where I have my script.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but have you tried using different encodings?

Comment: What encoding settings should I change?

Comment: or... i got an idea. go to some site that makes short urls (i.e dot.tk or tinyurl.com) and create a domain name that points to your domain that doesn't have åäö and use the in you AS3 code

Comment: Then i'm out of ideas, sorry but can't help you any further.

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestions. =) I finally managed to solve the problem by hosting most of the content on a different domain. The flash and html files are still on the åäö domain, but the server side stuff is on another domain without the åäö.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is stupid, but have you tried to connect to URL through the IP address directly?

Rob